# Map issue in Signed Android APK

Tags: android

I am integrating  google map  in my android application. its working fine but when i create singed Apk then map is not loading. i have already register SHA with google console and using same apikey on client side.

```
created Android Key on google console by using 

            SHA;packageName

and using APIKey on client side like below enter code here

            <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCnHDmWm5mvImsEvsva75BS__Gl9FmIE2k" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the SHA1 key you are using is of debug mode. While creating a signed apk using keystore you will find an another SHA1 at keystore file. Use that key and create new android key of map. This is the released mode version. Use this key as map key....... It will show the map perfectly on release mode.

Note: for debug mode use that previous key.